# how to generate Trx wallet without using API

Tags: php, cryptography, tron

base on [TRX documents](https://developers.tron.network/docs/account) and some search in GitHub I tried to generate wallet offline and I can't use API for some reasons.

## based on Trx documents I should do these steps :

> 1. Generate a key pair and extract the public key (a 64-byte byte array representing its x,y coordinates).
> 2. Hash the public key using sha3-256 function and extract the last 20 bytes of the result.
> 3. Add 0x41 to the beginning of the byte array. The length of the initial address should be 21 bytes.
> 4. Hash the address twice using sha256 function and take the first 4 bytes as verification code.
> 5. Add the verification code to the end of the initial address and get an address in base58check format through base58 encoding.
> 6. An encoded Mainnet address begins with T and is 34 bytes in length.
>
> **Please note: the sha3 protocol adopted is KECCAK-256.**

I find `mattvb91/tron-trx-php` in GitHub and this repository there is a wallet generator method `/src/Wallet.php` but the generated key validation return an Error Exception and validation get failed.

I try to recode `mattvb91/tron-trx-php` Wallet generator method and create my wallet generator

```
class walletGenerator
    {

        private $addressPrefix = "41";
        private $addressPrefixByte = 0x41;
        private $addressSize = 34;

        public function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function generateWallet()
        {
            $key = new Key();

            $odd = false;
            while (!$odd)
            {
                $keyPair = $key->GenerateKeypair();
                if(strlen($keyPair['public_key']) % 2 == 0) $odd = true;
            }

            $privateKeyHex = $keyPair['private_key_hex'];
            $pubKeyHex = $keyPair['public_key'];

            $pubKeyBin = hex2bin($pubKeyHex);
            $addressHex = $this->getAddressHex($pubKeyBin);
            $addressBin = hex2bin($addressHex);
            $addressBase58 = $this->getBase58CheckAddress($addressBin);
            $validAddress = $this->validateAddress($addressBase58);

        }

        private function getAddressHex($pubKeyBin)
        {
            if (strlen($pubKeyBin) == 65) {
                $pubKeyBin = substr($pubKeyBin, 1);
            }

            $hash = Keccak::hash($pubKeyBin , 256);
            $hash = substr($hash, 24);

            return $this->addressPrefix . $hash;
        }

        private function getBase58CheckAddress($addressBin){
            $hash0 = Hash::SHA256($addressBin);
            $hash1 = Hash::SHA256($hash0);
            $checksum = substr($hash1, 0, 4);
            $checksum = $addressBin . $checksum;
            $result = Base58::encode(Crypto::bin2bc($checksum));

            return $result;
        }

        private function validateAddress($walletAddress){
            if(strlen($walletAddress) !== $this->addressSize) return false;

            $address = Base58Check::decode($walletAddress , false , 0 , false);
            $utf8 = hex2bin($address);

            if(strlen($utf8) !== 25) return false;
            if(strpos($utf8 , $this->addressPrefixByte) !== 0) return false; // strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior

            $checkSum = substr($utf8, 21);
            $address = substr($utf8, 0, 21);


            $hash0 = Hash::SHA256($address);
            $hash1 = Hash::SHA256($hash0);
            $checkSum1 = substr($hash1, 0, 4);

            if ($checkSum === $checkSum1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

## Here is my problems :

1. `validateAddress` method has an Error Exception
2. when I add Private Key in Trx Wallets manually the detected wallet address is different from the generated Address.

```
if(strpos($utf8 , $this->addressPrefixByte) !== 0) return false; // strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior
```

## additional information

I used `ionux/phactor` to generating keyPair and `iexbase/tron-api` Support classes for Hash and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can debug and solved the problem and share the solutions with you

## nowhere is the solutions

#### this line of code has an Error Exception

```
if(strpos($utf8 , $this->addressPrefixByte) !== 0) return false; // strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior
```

this problem because of PHP 7.3 bugs and fix with PHP 7.2 ( [Exception: stripos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior #770](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/770) )

#### and addresses differences

in the Key Pair array, I remove `0x` from first of *Private Key Hex* and I can access to the wallet in Tron Link Extention don't remember to have a transition for wallet activation